# Does suspending a process (time.sleep()) in python suspend the thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a process running in a python script. Within it, I have launched a thread that is listening to a tcp socket. To save on CPU Cycles/context switching, i've put a time.sleep(1) in that processes while loop, so when it starts running again, it will check some flag set by the thread.

Will this work?

Comment: Can you add some code that demonstrates exactly what's you're trying here? It's not clear to me how many process/threads you have, and in which of those you want to call `time.sleep`. I can say that `time.sleep` will only cause the thread you ran it in to go to sleep; all other threads will continue running. I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're asking, though.

Comment: Network read call typically block anyway, so the sleep call is then pointless.

Comment: [`time.sleep()` suspends execution of the *calling thread* **only**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) i.e., all other threads will continue to run